# Sharepoint Taxonomy Update Scheduler

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a question on Taxonomy Update Scheduler.

Here is the scenario.

I have custom list which is using Managed Metadata field in the list(This list is attached with Itemupdating event to send email notification)

First we created few items with this manamged metadata values and save the items. After some time we updated term store names which were used in the list items. Then ran Taxonomy Update Scheduler timer job from sharepoint central admin and once the timer job ran sucessfully the custom list items were reflecting the changes.

But after item got updated event is not triggering in custom list which supposed to send the mail notification. Is the sharepoint is not supporting this behavior?

Can anyone please guide me on this issue.

Regards
Anand

Answer (score 0):

No event is raised when Taxonomy data is changed. Managed Metadata field is an Enhanced Lookup field type so the content of field doesn't change when timer runs. In detail the Managed Metadata field contain a reference (ID) of an item (Term) that Sharepoint automatically add to /Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList in the SiteCollection root. I suppose that the Metadata Timer job modify that hidden list items instead.